A free website for creating a personal Repo for "Debian"
Do you know a free website for creating a personal Repo?
Like launchpad.net but it can used for Debian?
I don't want a free server. I want a easy platform for releasing my package in a Repo for another, but for Debian. Like https://proget.makedeb.org

confused. Your title says "free server", your last sentence says "not a free server". Maybe you could be a bit clearer about what you need specifically?

I’m voting to close this question because it is primarily about web-hosting.

A debian repository is just a HTTP server, serving a specific directory structure. So, anything that allows you to host your own websites works; there's a myriad free website hosts, from github pages to the free tier of various cloud compute providers. for some, you will need to check with their terms whether hosting software is fine, but other than that, "where to host my website" is a bit of an overly broad question.
Other than that, if you're developing software for debian, what about you register an account on the debian developer gitlab, https://salsa.debian.org , and join their community? Getting interesting software at least into experimental can be pretty straightforward.
That of course is only possible if your software is license-compatible with debian, but I'd argue that if it isn't, you spending a few Euros a year on your own webserver space is probably not a problem.
